# How do I close a navigation drawer after an item is selected?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a navigation drawer and everything functions properly. The navigation drawer contains a listview and when an item is selected, the main fragment is replaced properly.

This is the onClickListener code:

```
mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HeaderViewListAdapter headerView = (HeaderViewListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        AccountAdapter adapter = (AccountAdapter) headerView.getWrappedAdapter();
        Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();

        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            ((NavigationDrawerCallbacks) getActivity()).onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_COLUMN)));
        }
    }
});
```

And in my activity, the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method is like this:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(long accountId) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainFragment, AccountDetailFragment.newInstance(accountId))
            .commit();
}
```

As I said, this functions, but the navigation drawer remains open. It's a hassle for the user to have to select an account from the listview and then have to close the drawer to see the main fragment, so how can I have it close automatically, so that when an item is selected the only visible element is the main fragment (and everything inside of it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `closeDrawer()` on the `DrawerLayout` object with either the Drawer `View`, or the Drawer's `Gravity` as an argument.

Comment: I experimented with it and I put it in `onItemClick` method and it worked. I passed in the view as the argument. Since I used the auto generated code for a NavigationDrawer, I'm going to comment for future users that `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);` did the trick.

Comment: Yeah, wherever you have access to the `DrawerLayout` object will work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I tried digging through some docs, but never thought to look into `DrawerLayout` documentation, and Google searches didn't lead me directly there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the closeDrawer inside the onItemClick, when the Drawer Layout is not null.

```
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
```